# Sqoop - Import failed: cannot convert sql type -102

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, sqoop, avro

When I try to run on Sqoop the command:

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//MyServer/MyDatabase
>   --username MyUser --password MyPassword -m 1 --table MyTable --fetch-size 10 --create-hive-table --hive-table LocalTable --as-avrodatafile --target-dir /user/sample

I am getting the following error:

> Import failed: cannot convert sql type -102

Is it because I am trying to generate an avro?
Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you inspect the columns in the Oracle table, to check whether it contains weird data types such as BLOB etc?

Comment: And since you ask the question, did you try to import the table as TextFile? Generally speaking, did you try **anything** to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I keept investigating but I didn't update my researches here. I will answer myself in a few minutes in case anyone else may face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and a solution.

The error message meant that avro was not able to convert one of the columns because of its data type. The problem was exactly with a date format.

The solution was to add this in the sqoop command:

--map-column-java DATE_COLUMN=String

With this we do a castin to string, and avro doesnt complain anymore

Just to add a few tips more:

1. In case you need to cast in several columns, use a ',' between elements and don't leave white spaces:

   --map-column-java DATE_COLUMN1=String,DATE_COLUMN2=String
2. The variable type must be written with first letter in Uppercase

   --map-column-java COLUMN1=String,COLUMN2=Integer